# how to call web api in controller and return into view MVC4

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, client, getjson

I have a project using MVC4, i want to ask how to get data from webapi and return into view.

**Model**

```
public class Name
{
    public Int32 NameId { get; set; }
    public String FirstName{ get; set; }
    public String LastName{ get; set; }
    public String CreatedBy { get; set; }
}

public class IListMyProject
{
    public List<Name> Names { get; set; }
}
```

I can list all in my `Index.cshtml` using this code

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string securityToken = repo.GetTokens();
        if (securityToken != null)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "webapiurl/api/Name/Get?$orderby=LastName&$top=10");
            string authHeader = System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString();
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add(authHeader, string.Format("JWT {0}", securityToken));
            var response = client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage)
                .ContinueWith((postTask) => postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode())
                .Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                model.Names = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<Name>>().Result.ToList();

            }
        }
        return View("Index", model);
    }
```

i can return my view. and now i have another view called Details.cshtml with this code :

```
 public ActionResult Details(string id)
    {
        string securityToken = repo.GetTokens();
        if (securityToken != null)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "webapiurl/api/Name/GetById/"+id+"");
            string authHeader = System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString();
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add(authHeader, string.Format("JWT {0}", securityToken));

            var response = client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage)
                .ContinueWith((postTask) => postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode())
                .Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

                model.Names = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<Name>>().Result.ToList();

            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

For this Detail, my Json looks like this:

```
 application/json, text/json
 {
  "NameId": 1,
  "FirstName": "This is First Name",
  "LastName": "This is Last Name",
  "CreatedBy": "This is Created By"
 }
```

when i run it, i get this error :

```
 Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Models.Name]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

 To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

 Path 'NameId', line 1, position 10.
```

How do i fix this, im new to webapi. i wonder why do if i list all (for index, i use api/get) it works, but when i want to show it in detail, it doesn't work.

thank for help

Regards

**EDIT**

when i debug in

```
 model.Names = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<Name>>().Result.ToList();
```

its says Null, is there something wrong when i try to get the response ?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that:

```
{
  "NameId": 1,
  "FirstName": "This is First Name",
  "LastName": "This is Last Name",
  "CreatedBy": "This is Created By"
}
```

can't be deserialized as an IList. The JSON you have above is just one name, not a collection of Names. So Json.NET deserialization will fail.

Make sure that your Web API controller returns an IList, or change your MVC code to read the content as a single Name. A collection of names in JSON would look like this instead:

```
[{
  "NameId": 1,
  "FirstName": "This is First Name",
  "LastName": "This is Last Name",
  "CreatedBy": "This is Created By"
},
{
  "NameId": 2,
  "FirstName": "This is First Name",
  "LastName": "This is Last Name",
  "CreatedBy": "This is Created By"
}]
```

Comment: i think that is my problem. but i dont make the webapi, i just use it in my mvc. how to list that json? thank bro

Comment: well then read the content as a Name, not as an IList<Name> if you don't control the web service...

Comment: i use 

    var NamesId = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Models.Name>().Result;

and when i debug on NamesId, i can get the result. but how i can return into Details.cshtml view ?

Answer (score 1):

The Web API is returning a single object of type **Name**, not a collections of **Name**.  I do not see where you define **model**. I added a definition of type **Name**. Try this.

```
public ActionResult Details(string id)
{
    string securityToken = repo.GetTokens();
    Name model;
    if (securityToken != null)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "webapiurl/api/Name/GetById/"+id+"");
        string authHeader = System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString();
        httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add(authHeader, string.Format("JWT {0}", securityToken));

        var response = client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage)
            .ContinueWith((postTask) => postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode())
            .Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {

            model = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Name>();

        }
    }
    return  View(model);
}
```

Comment: hi there, i try this one and the result is "value cannot be null".

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand the original question. Take a look at my updated answer to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be the fact that your JSON returns only 1 record while you are Reading the result as `IList<Name>`. Changing it to simply `Name` should fix the problem.

However you question is: "**how to call web api in controller and return into view MVC4**"

I recommend you to look at http://restsharp.org/ You can simplify your code to:

```
public ActionResult Details(string id)
{
    string securityToken = repo.GetTokens();
    Name model;
    if (securityToken != null)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("");

        var request = new RestRequest("webapiurl/api/Name/GetById/"+id, HttpMethod.Get);
        string authHeader = System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString();
        request.AddHeader(authHeader, string.Format("JWT {0}", securityToken));

        var model = client.Execute<Name>(request);
    }
    return  View(model);
}
```